Python glob not finding files with specified pattern
I'm stuck with this script, when I run it with the full file name it finds the file just fine and runs the importer but when I try and use * for some reason it just gives me "No files found for pattern...". For context it's a containerized console application running on Linux. Any input would be appreciated.
import pexpect
import glob
import os

command = 'sudo docker run --network sacrranetwork -it -v "/home/sftpuser/sftp":/mnt 328654361699.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/sacrra:230'

operations = [
    ('1', '/mnt/Forward Flow Sale*', 'Please enter the path of the TFG Sales file you want to import:'),
    ('2', '/mnt/IDC_ARC_ACTION_*.csv', 'Please enter the path of the Action file you want to import:'),
    ('3', '/mnt/IDC_ARC_AOD_*.csv', 'Please enter the path of the AOD file you want to import:'),
    ('4', '/mnt/IDC_ARC_DEBTOR_INFO_*.csv', 'Please enter the path of the Debtor Info file you want to import:'),
    ('5', '/mnt/IDC_ARC_FEE_*.csv', 'Please enter the path of the Fee file you want to import:'),
    ('6', '/mnt/IDC_ARC_Payment_*.csv', 'Please enter the path of the Payment file you want to import:'),
    ('7', '/mnt/IDC_ARC_PaymentReversal_*.csv', 'Please enter the path of the Payment Reversal file you want to import:'),
    ('8', '/mnt/report_All_Payments_Incl_Balances_*.csv', 'Please enter the path of the Swordfish payment file you want to import:'),
    ('9', '/mnt/report_Debtors_Per_Client_*.csv', 'Please enter the path of the Debtors per Client file you want to import:'),
    ('10', '', 'Please enter the path of the EDC Hand Over file you want to import:')
]

expanded_operations = []

for operation, file_pattern, prompt in operations:
    if '*' in file_pattern:
        print(f"Checking for files with pattern: {file_pattern}")
        expanded_files = glob.glob(file_pattern)
        print(f"Expanded files for pattern {file_pattern}: {expanded_files}")
        if expanded_files:
            first_file = expanded_files[0]
            expanded_operations.append((operation, first_file, prompt))
        else:
            print(f"No files found for pattern {file_pattern}")
    else:
        print(f"Checking for file: {file_pattern}")
        if os.path.exists(file_pattern):
            expanded_operations.append((operation, file_pattern, prompt))
        else:
            print(f"File not found: {file_pattern}")

for operation, file_path, prompt in expanded_operations:
    if operation == '10':
        break

    child = pexpect.spawn(command, encoding='utf-8', timeout=60)

    try:
        while True:
            line = child.readline().strip()
            if line:
                print(line)
            if 'Please select the operation you like would to perform:' in line:
                child.sendline(operation)
            if prompt in line:
                child.sendline(file_path)
            if 'Press any key to exit..' in line:
                child.sendline('')
                break
    except pexpect.EOF:
        print("Reached EOF")
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
        print("Timeout exceeded while waiting for output")

    child.close()

exit

When I run the script with the full file path it works, example below:
('2', '/mnt/IDC_ARC_ACTION_20240516.csv', 'Please enter the path of the Action file you want to import:'),

The moment I remove the date and use a wildcard along with glob it does not find the file. I tried various * placements. Also when I run the container manually and enter the file path I don't encounter any issues.
Here is the ouput from the console I'm getting:
Checking for files with pattern: /mnt/IDC_ARC_ACTION_*.csv
Expanded files for pattern /mnt/IDC_ARC_ACTION_*.csv: []
No files found for pattern /mnt/IDC_ARC_ACTION_*.csv


Please always provide a [mre], most of the code here is irrelevant to the problem and only obfuscates it.

Sorry this is my first time posting on this platform and I was not sure how much code to provide.

Do you really have regular files under /mnt? One usually has mount points there.

I was not sure how much code to provide Exactly the code that everyone can copy, paste and run. No more and no less. This means you do not post fragments of your real program, you post a small, possibly written from scratch, program that has the same problem.

I tried your code on Google Collab with the files I have created. The file names are:
[example.txt, example1.txt,example2.txt].
When I run the code, it gives the correct output.The problem might be the paths you have provided. Here are the code and outputs:
import glob
import os

operations = [
    ('1', '/content/example*', 'Please enter the path of the TFG Sales file you want to import:')
]

expanded_operations = []

for operation, file_pattern, prompt in operations:
    if '*' in file_pattern:
        print(f"Checking for files with pattern: {file_pattern}")
        expanded_files = glob.glob(file_pattern)
        print(f"Expanded files for pattern {file_pattern}: {expanded_files}")
        if expanded_files:
            first_file = expanded_files[0]
            expanded_operations.append((operation, first_file, prompt))
        else:
            print(f"No files found for pattern {file_pattern}")

The output:
Checking for files with pattern: /content/example*
Expanded files for pattern /content/example*: ['/content/example folder', '/content/example1.txt', '/content/example2.txt', '/content/example.txt']

